# Show multiple Ajax html response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The `$('.my-button').click(function(e)` function is supposed to show the output of the display.php, which just contains some mysql query and the output in html. 
It works so far, but as I am looping the button itself for each post, the function only works for the first button. I need to make the script understand, that for each button it should only show the results for that button. But how to insert some individual ID to the `$(".responsecontainer").html(response);`? I tried with `$(".responsecontainer" + id).html(response);` getting "id" before via parameters, but it seems that this id must be hardcoded.

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.my-button').click(function(e) {                
  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to display.php
    type: "GET",
    url: "display.php",             
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        $(".responsecontainer").html(response); 
        //alert(response);
    }
```

And this is the button and DIV to show results:

```
<input type="button" class="my-button" value="'.$plus.'" />
<div class="responsecontainer" id="'.$plus.'" align="center">
</div>
```

Noting that `$plus` is always unique.

Comment: You should only need `$('#id').html(response)` for each container if the id's are unique *as they should be*.I think your problem is that each button should be individually identified somehow.

Comment: Tried with `$('#id').html(response);`  and `<div class="responsecontainer" id="'.$plus.'" align="center">` but doesn't work.

Comment: Hold on, I am working up something, testing some code. Is each div truly a sibling to the input button?

Comment: `$(this).siblings(".responsecontainer").html(response)` I think @JayBlanchard ?

Comment: Only if that is true - but he does have a matching bit of data.

Comment: $(".responsecontainer") will return you and array.

Comment: Well the DIV is right below the Button always, just like the code above.

Comment: Too little html given. Is each button and response div inside of an element together? Or are all buttons and response divs just piled together inside a single parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `data-attributes` to store the related DIV's id.
- When a button is clicked get the `data-attribute`, i.e: `data-target-id`.
- With that `id` you can execute a selector as follow: `#div_1` and insert the received HTML.
- ***DON'T*** use value to target your DIV, the button's value is the text for your buttons, just imagine if your button texts are filled using a kind of i18n translation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.my-button').click(function(e) {
      var targetId = $(this).data('target-id');
      /*$.ajax({ //create an ajax request to display.php
          type: "GET",
          url: "display.php",
          dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
          success: function(response) {*/
            $(`#${targetId}`).html(`Response = ${targetId}`);
          /*});
      });*/
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" data-target-id='div_1' class="my-button" value="Click me!" />
<div id='div_1' class="responsecontainer" align="center">
</div>

<input type="button" data-target-id='div_2' class="my-button" value="Click me!" />
<div id='div_2' class="responsecontainer" align="center">
</div>

<input type="button" data-target-id='div_3' class="my-button" value="Click me!" />
<div id='div_3' class="responsecontainer" align="center">
</div>
```

Comment: @IncredibleHat if you're *unsure*, why did you downvote this with so much confidence?

Comment: @IncredibleHat sorry!

Comment: The OP already has matching data, so need to add a data attribute. What is the harm of using the button's value? It isn't going to change. If you're going to say not to do something, tell us why so we can all learn something.

Comment: True that @JayBlanchard ... I worry his values may have adverse conflicts with it simply being placed in a `id` like he has though. Especially in any of those `$plus` have spaces, or other non-id safe characters.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's ugly/bad, Etc at any scale, imagine I18n for these buttons.

Comment: Ugly/bad how? I must be missing something.

Comment: I did read that, but you would run into the same problem if you don't hard-code the data- attributes. What if the OP isn't using internationalization? Should he worry then?

Comment: @JayBlanchard well, the OP has to decide what it's better for him/her.

Comment: That's true, but it still doesn't settle the question.

Comment: If the `div.responsecontainer` is going to be immediately placed after the `my-button`, you can just do away with the IDs/data-IDs and use `button.next('.responsecontainer').html(...)` where `button = $(this)` (placed before the AJAX call).

Comment: So, here is the deal @BobMorane you have to make sure that whatever you use to set the id's that the id's have no space and use no internationalized characters. It doesn't matter which code block you use, what matters is that you have usable matching data between the button and the div as demonstrated in both examples.

Comment: If whatever was being dropped in from `$plus` is considered clean and controlled, then I have no issues with what @JayBlanchard presented, as it will work straight out of the box. But if `$plus` was... forbid... user input from a database... eek, then yeah, precautions need to be taken with it... or make new attributes like Ele presented.

Comment: Exactly @IncredibleHat, so when the OP changes the code to use data attributes he is still likely to drop in a dynamic value, like `$plus`, to create the `data-target-id` and the div's `id`.

Comment: Right @JayBlanchard. When I meant make new attributes like Ele presented, I assumed that the value in those attributes would clean and NOT from `$plus`... otherwise its as you say... garbage in garbage crash!

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of the button and the id of the div are the same (`$plus`) just capture the button's value and use that to tell you which div to update:

```
$('.my-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var buttonVal = $(this).val(); // the value of the button which should match the id of the container to be updated
    var response = 'button ' + buttonVal + ' clicked';
    $('#' + buttonVal).html(response); 

})
```

Here is a an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gz1errzv/).

Assuming the button is a sibling of the div (as stated in comments) the code becomes this, with no id needed for the div:

```
$('.my-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var buttonVal = $(this).val(); // just using this to get something to display
    var response = 'button ' + buttonVal + ' clicked'; // same here
    $(this).next('div').html(response); 

})
```

Here is that [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gz1errzv/1/).